# Can we say that $A$ is a complement for a group $G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a frobenius complement for a $G$ i.e. $A$ act on $G$ by automorphism s.t. $C_A(g)=e$ for all nonidentity $g$.

Now, Action of $A$ can be linearly extended so that $A$ act on $F[G]$. As a result we can see $F[G]$ as a $F[A]$ module. Let $\chi$ be corresponding character of $A$ then

$$\ \chi(g) = \begin{cases} 
      |G| & \textrm{ if $g=e$ } \\
      1 & \textrm{ if $g\neq e$ } \\
   \end{cases} \ $$
as one can easily compute.

Now, I am asking the converse of this situation; if $A$ has a character $\chi$ s.t.

$$\ \chi(g) = \begin{cases} 
      n & \textrm{ if $g=e$ } \\
      1 & \textrm{ if $g\neq e$ } \\
   \end{cases} \ $$

then can we say that $A$ is a frobenius complement for a group of order $n$ ?

**Note:** $F$ can be taken as $\mathbb C$ complex field.

Comment: You should mention somewhere that this has now been answered on mathoverflow.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I have mentioned there but I forgot here. You are right.

Comment: Above question is answered by @GeoffRobinson as;Take $n=1+pq$, where $p,q$ are primes with $q|p−1$. Let A be a non-Abelian group of order $pq$. Then $A$ is not a Frobenius complement, but A does have a (complex) character which takes value n on the identity and 1 everywhere else. The character in question is the sum of the trivial character and the regular character.